# Convert UK date to US date in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

Hi there seems to be plenty out there to convert a US formatted date (MM/DD/YYYY) to a UK date (DD/MM/YYYY), but I'm trying to do the opposite: i receive a load of UK dates (DD-MM-YYYY) from the server which I'm trying to format as DD-MMM-YYYY (eg: 11 Jan 2013 ), but Flex thinks it's trying to convert American days and so when it gets 17-02-2013, it returns an empty string because there is no month 17.
How do i tell it I'm giving it UK dates and not US dates? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you receive dates as `String` or `Date` value types?

Comment: String. Sorry, that would indeed have been useful information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, you can't.

Longer answer, there's not enough information to determine the date format.  As you saw, in some cases you CAN determine that the date is not valid for the expected format (17-02-2013 - since 17 isn't a valid month, it must be DD-MM-YYYY rather than MM-DD-YYYY), but for just under half of the dates you just can't tell (is 01-02-2013 supposed to be Jan 2 or Feb 1?)

If you DO know that the dates are supposed to be in a particular format, you can use DateField.stringToDate to parse the string:

```
var value:Date = DateField.stringToDate(dateString, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, got round it in the end with this ugly hack: ended up converting the string into an array and re-organising it so that it would fit the american format before using the DateFormatter.format on the result. There must be a more elegant way...

```
<Script>

    public convertDateStringToUS( date : String ) : String
    {
       var dateArray : Array = date.split( "-" );
       var day = dateArray[0];
       var month = dateArray[1];
       var year = dateArray[2];
       date = month + "-" + day + "-" + year;
       return date
    }

</Script>

<declarations>

    <mx:DateFormatter id="dateFormatter" 
                      formatString="DD-MMM-YYYY" />

</declarations>

<s:Label id="myDateLabel"
         text =" { dateFormatter.format( convertDateStringToUS( date ) ) } "/>
```